# React Native Color property is not working

Tags: react-native

> Blockquote

**code**

```
   <Text style ={styles.header}>
     Flex
   </Text>

   header: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 55,
    color: 'red',
  }
```

**Problem**
The color property is not changing, all the properties of Text are working instead of color

Answer (score 0):

Change `style` like this:

```
<Text h1 style={styles.header}>
```

should be work

Comment: i have change to <Text style = {styles.header} > only color property is not working rather than that all properties of Text are working

Comment: Could you update your new code let us review again? It should be something wrong there.

Comment: Or try `color: "#13E5F5"` to `color: "red"` if it works? Because I have tried your code, and it works fine.

Comment: i have change to red but still it is not working, all properties are working fontSize, fotWeight etc only this color property is not working, Is this due to version@0.62.2 of react native or this does not work on new android version such as Pie or oreo ?

Comment: yeah, I think you could down grade to stable [v0.62.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.62.0) could avoid facing error if they are trying some code.

Comment: I found some change color at [v0.63.0-rc.1 update](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.63.0-rc.1) , but not sure if it is the problem from.

Comment: it is working on android nougat but it is not working on android Pie, So can i get help with that please

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `style` not `h1style`. As there are no props named `h1style`. Please refer below code

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text h1 style={styles.header}>
        Flex
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: 
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginTop: 55,
    color: "#13E5F5"
  }
});

export default App;
```

For more help please check the same code online on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wu-towxm?file=/src/App.js)

[image]

Comment: all the properties of color are working instead of color

Comment: @MuhammadAnasKhan, You can check this on https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wu-towxm?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

`h1style` is not a valid props name in react native. You need to use `style` instead of `h1style`.

```
<Text h1 style={styles.header}>
```

Comment: I have changed from h1style to style but it is not working, all the properties of Text are working instead of color

Comment: Try by removing h1 as well. I think it would work by removing h1 props.

Comment: i have remove h1 but still only the color property is not working else fontSize, fontWeight etc are working

Comment: It is working on android nougat but not on android pie